# Jquery UI dialog will not close on first try, takes several clicks

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery-UI dialog library but when I try to close it, there seems to have been several identical dialogs beneath it that had spawned, and it takes several clicks to close them all. Sometimes the buttons in the dialog are unresponsive.

```
        if (!($(clicked).attr("type")) || ($(clicked).attr("type") == "text")){
            newDialog("What Would You Like To Type Here ?",
            "test");
            return false;
        }
function newDialog(mytitle, mycontent){
   var $dialog = $('<div id="myunique"></div>')
        .html(mycontent)
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: false,           
            title: mytitle,
            width: 500
        });
    $dialog.dialog('open'); 

    //return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check to see if $dialog has been created, if not, create it.  That way you'll only create one dialog, rather than creating a new one each time you want to open it.

```
var $dialog = null;
function newDialog(mytitle, mycontent){
    if ( $dialog != null ){
        $dialog = $('<div id="myunique"></div>')
            .html(mycontent)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: false,           
                title: mytitle,
                width: 500
            });
    }
    $dialog.dialog('open'); 

    //return false;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the most sensible solution, checking to see if $dialog has been created or not, guarantees only one instance of it is open. I have also added `e.StopPropagation()` after `.dialog('open')` not sure if that also helps.

Answer (score 3):

You should not create a new dialog div DOM element each time you want to show one.

Instead, create one div which will be used for your dialog and change it’s content and visibility.

/e:
(I had a similiar / the same issue some time back this year. Unfortunately I don’t remember what the issue was for me, nor can I find it in my code history of the project. I fixed it somehow. AFAIK either via using one DOM element instead of creating new ones, or by removing them again.)

Comment: the thing is depending on the element clicked, I need a dialogue with different actions and options.

Comment: then you need to manage the list of different dialogs you need to display - don't re-use the same variable.

Comment: which same variable ? I am confused

Comment: `var $dialog` is what he meant. You re-used that variable (name) for all your dialog elements.